# How can I set up a stack frame for sigreturn myself?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, signals, coroutine

I am trying to set up a stack frame for the syscall `sigreturn`. The syscall reads the info on stack top(it is a ucontext_t struct) and atomically set signal mask and set `rip`. But I am not good at `asm`, this is my code:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <pthread.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void sigreturn_to(ucontext_t *ctx) {
    register void *rsp __asm__("rsp");
    rsp -= sizeof(ucontext_t);
    *(ucontext_t*)rsp = *ctx;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov $15, %%rax\n\t"
        "syscall"
        :
        :
        :
    );
}

void come_here() {
    while (1) {
        printf("123\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    ucontext_t ctx;
    getcontext(&ctx);
    void *main_stack = malloc(40960);
    sigemptyset(&ctx.uc_sigmask);
    ctx.uc_link = NULL;
    ctx.uc_stack.ss_sp = main_stack;
    ctx.uc_stack.ss_size = 40960;
    makecontext(&ctx, come_here, 0);

    sigreturn_to(&ctx);
}
```

My goal is to atomically set signal mask and `jmp` to a function(siglongjmp and setcontext just call `sigprocmask` and set `rip`, they are not atomic). So I want to use sigreturn syscall to achieve this.

The program failed to jmp to `come_here` function, I think it's the reason is that I set a wrong stack frame. Can you tell me how to set the stack frame correctly?

Comment: `register void *rsp __asm__("rsp");` has no guaranteed effect except as an `"r"` operand for an `asm` statement.  Even with older GCC where the documentation said something stronger, I doubt that subtract would actually work to make your own stack frame.  Also, your `asm` statement has no `"memory"` clobber, so no guaranteed effect.  https://godbolt.org/z/WPjbcETEM shows that using `"r"(rsp)` *does* get GCC to `sub $968, %rsp` before the asm statement, but either way it does store (otherwise to 968 below RSP, well below the red-zone!)

Comment: If this works, I suspect it's still not guaranteed and the function should probably be written in pure asm.  Or use `alloca` or something to get a stack array, unless RSP has to actually point at the data for the kernel.